# What Visual Studio workloads are needed for building VS extensions?

Tags: visual-studio

We've already added the Visual Studio workload *Visual Studio Extensions Development*, but that doesn't seem to be enough. So, are there other workloads that should be installed on a developer's machine, to author VS extensions?

**Addendum**

I should mention that the users struggling to add *Visual Studio Extension Development* are using Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition. I would think this would work, but I could be wrong. Can you do Visual Studio development with the Community Edition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Visual Studio extension development** + **.NET desktop development** workloads should be enough for most VS extensions.

Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition is perfectly fine to do Visual Studio development.